# How to programmatically detect with Python when a Cassandra node is being repaired or is done repairing

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

**Intro + Problem:**

I have a Python application using a Cassandra 1.2.4 cluster. Once every week I need to run the scheduled repairs on the Cassandra nodes (nodetool repair), and during that time I want to reduce the load on the node being repaired, but as soon as the repair finishes I want to start using the node normally. I'm using the CQL library from Python to access the cluster.

**The questions:**

Is there a simple way to know from a Python program when a Cassandra node is being repaired?, If not, is there a way of knowing when a repair is done knowing in advance that the repair has already started?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the dynamic snitch (enabled by default) should indirectly be able to route around a node or nodes that have a lot of load on them:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dynamic-snitching-in-cassandra-past-present-and-future

The other things you can do is look at nodetool netstats and compactionstats on all the nodes participating in the repair to see if there is streaming or compactions relating to repair (validation type compactions) going on.  Obviously running nodetool or using the JMX equivalents are tricky with Python, but just trying to give you some ideas.

Also in 1.1.9/1.2.1, there was a ticket that allowed for monitoring the progress of a repair through a jmx initiated repair call.  For other details see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4767

Work is being done with Cassandra 2.0+ to make both repair and streaming more resilient and able to be monitored.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5286

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, even a few ideas are really helpful for me because we lack some functionality when it comes to this kind of tasks, at least from Python.